# Bootstrap Collapse DIV automatically hides when scrolling on mobile

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am editing an existing website using **Bootstrap** framework and using `data-toggle="collapse"` **HTML** option to show/hide specified DIV on mobile screen.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-block hidden-lg" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#text">Show</button>
<div class="collapse in" id="text">
Text
</div>
```

But there is one problem. On my mobile (Android OS), I click "Show" button and see content of DIV, then scroll down website and DIV automatically hides. How to prevent from hiding DIV when I scroll down my website?

Tried methods:

- Upgraded **Bootstrap** to the newest version;
- Added CSS options like `z-index:1000`;
- Visited many Stackow pages with similar questions.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately there's not enough to work with here. This markup should work, and does for countless others. You'll need to provide a demonstration of the problem.

Comment: What happens if you remove `hidden-lg`? Not knowing your screen size, I wonder if it's a factor.

Comment: When I remove `hidden-lg`, nothing happens, just the button does not hide on desktop screen.

Comment: I have fixed the problem, just changed the ID, which was overwritten somewhere...

Comment: Good to hear. Please provide and accept an answer or close your question. [Take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) if this doesn't make sense.